# Allocating dynamic memory for a variable inside a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Below is a small code and the goal is to learn and practice creating a database of student using structure with dynamic allocation of Marks obtained by each student. The problem i am running into is when i try to provide marks for each student here,

**scanf("%d",((students + i)->(ptr_marks + j)));**

```
// creating a structure with variable students and the marks they have obtained

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>

#define debugging

struct Student {
    int age;
    int roll_no;
    int* ptr_marks;
};

int main (void) {

// total number of students
    int num_students;
    printf("Enter # of Students: ");
    scanf("%d",&num_students);

// structure array definition
    struct Student* students;
    students = (struct Student*) malloc (num_students * sizeof(struct Student));
    assert(students != NULL);

    int marks;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < num_students ; i ++)   {

        (students + i )->roll_no = i + 1;
        (students + i )->age = i + 10;
        printf("Enter #'s of Subjects for Student %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d", &marks);

        // allocating memory for marks obtained by each student
        (students + i)->ptr_marks = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * marks);
        for (int j = 0 ; j < marks ; j ++)  {

            printf("Enter Mark for Subject %d: ", j+1);
            scanf("%d",((students + i)->(ptr_marks + j)));

        }
    }

#ifdef debugging

    for (int j = 0 ; j < num_students ; j ++)   {

        printf("The roll # of student %d are %d \n", j+1, (students+j)->roll_no);

    }

#endif

    free(students);
    //TODO
            // code to free up memory for marks
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what actual problem you are running into.

Comment: `(students + i)->(ptr_marks + j)` ought to be `(students + i)->ptr_marks + j` or more clear `&students[i].ptr_marks[j]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things more difficult on yourself attempting to use pointer notation rather than using array-index notation. For example, your allocation of `students` is fine, but see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714).

When you then start using students, while `(students + i)->roll_no = i + 1;` is technically fine, it is a bit more readable as: `students[i].roll_no = i + 1;`. The `[..]` acts as a dereference as well. Your allocation of each individual student `ptr_mark` would then be:

```
    students[i].ptr_marks = malloc (sizeof(int) * marks);
    assert (students[i].ptr_marks);
```

(**note:** validate each allocation)

The remainder are just clean-ups and being consistent with using array-index notion on `students[]...` and ensuring you ***validate every input***, e.g.

```
    for (int j = 0 ; j < marks ; j++)  {
        printf ("Enter Mark for Subject %d: ", j+1);
        if (scanf ("%d", &students[i].ptr_marks[j]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
```

You can then free all allocated blocks of memory with:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < num_students; i++)
        free (students[i].ptr_marks);      /* free storage for ptr_marks */
    free(students);                        /* free pointers */
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>

#define debugging

struct Student {
    int age;
    int roll_no;
    int* ptr_marks;
};

int main (void) {

    // total number of students
    int num_students;
    printf("Enter # of Students: ");
    if (scanf("%d",&num_students) != 1)
        return 1;

    // structure array definition
    struct Student *students;
    students = malloc (num_students * sizeof(struct Student));
    assert(students != NULL);

    int marks;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < num_students ; i ++)   {

        students[i].roll_no = i + 1;
        students[i].age = i + 10;
        printf("Enter #'s of Subjects for Student %d: ",i);
        if (scanf("%d", &marks) != 1)
            return 1;

        // allocating memory for marks obtained by each student
        students[i].ptr_marks = malloc (sizeof(int) * marks);
        assert (students[i].ptr_marks);
        for (int j = 0 ; j < marks ; j++)  {
            printf ("Enter Mark for Subject %d: ", j+1);
            if (scanf ("%d", &students[i].ptr_marks[j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
    }

#ifdef debugging

    for (int j = 0 ; j < num_students ; j ++)   {

        printf("The roll # of student %d are %d \n", j+1, (students+j)->roll_no);

    }

#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < num_students; i++)
        free (students[i].ptr_marks);
    free(students);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Exercising with miscellaneous input would result in:

```
$ ./bin/struct_ptr_alloc
Enter # of Students: 2
Enter #'s of Subjects for Student 0: 3
Enter Mark for Subject 1: 90
Enter Mark for Subject 2: 91
Enter Mark for Subject 3: 94
Enter #'s of Subjects for Student 1: 3
Enter Mark for Subject 1: 87
Enter Mark for Subject 2: 72
Enter Mark for Subject 3: 93
The roll # of student 1 are 1
The roll # of student 2 are 2
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/struct_ptr_alloc
==5051== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5051== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5051== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5051== Command: ./bin/struct_ptr_alloc
==5051==
Enter # of Students: 2
Enter #'s of Subjects for Student 0: 2
Enter Mark for Subject 1: 99
Enter Mark for Subject 2: 100
Enter #'s of Subjects for Student 1: 2
Enter Mark for Subject 1: 89
Enter Mark for Subject 2: 92
The roll # of student 1 are 1
The roll # of student 2 are 2
==5051==
==5051== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5051==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5051==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 2,096 bytes allocated
==5051==
==5051== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5051==
==5051== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5051== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi David,
Thanks for the response and i understand using arrays makes the implementation easy to understand and implement. Also i forgot about using valgrind for memory leaks after compilation so that is a good reminder. If i go with pointer route how would you do it because array implementation is simple.

Comment: If you go the pointer route you simply have to remember that `students[i] == *(students + i)` The key is keeping track of when you have a pointer and when you have a struct. Your use of `(students + i)->...` was correct, but when you get to `(students + i)->ptr_marks + j` -- it is a train-wreck to look at. Your choice, but `&students[i].ptr_marks[j]` is a lot more readable `:)`

Comment: got it, i am working on my C these days so i can sneak in from hardware engineering to firmware engineering :)

Comment: Good luck to you there. I've had some fun playing with a few of TI's microcontrollers. That's a whole additional layer of applying coding to hardware. When you get down to the level of pin comparators and catching data on rise/fall edge or up/down of a modulation -- you really appreciate how much as been done on x86 to separate hardware/software aspects of programming.

Comment: any good links which you can suggest that have good problems to solve?

Comment: That's the frustrating part. TI has good documentation and good examples (organized in a jumble of hunt and peck for the information you need pdfs) They also provide a higher level interfaces for GPIO and UART, etc.. that interject additional headers and mask the actual pin operations. The Keil compiler has several examples as well, but none of the higher level interface (at least not for the TI MSP432). Each of the microcontrollers are different with different interfaces. Example the TI RMX46 Hercules Safety Series, has little in common with the MSP432. (makes it a challenge...)

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to dynamically allocate the both struct and data use zero (or variable  )length array in the struct instead of pointer.

```
typedef struct {
    int age;
    int roll_no;
    int ptr_marks[0]; // or int ptr_marks[0] 
 } student;
```

Then you can dynamically allocate and reallocate the whole object.

```
student *allocstudent(student *st, size_t nmarks)
{
     student *tmp = realloc(st, sizeof *st + nmarks * sizeof(st-> marks[0]));
    return tmp;
}
```